# Why is JTable not updating renderer after changeSelection

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel, tablecelleditor

I am using changeSelection(int row, int column, boolean toggle, boolean extend) in Java's JTable. I have made it so that when the table has a checkbox column and that column is clicked, an event is sent to show that now the row is checked / unchecked all that is fine when it is done by a user. But when it is done programmatically, event is fired but the JTable does not refresh renderer, am I supposed to add something else. It is supposed to show that now the checkbox is ticked but no.

This is the code I am using to fire event programmatically.

```
boolean success = editCellAt(row, col); // col is a known checkbox column number
if (success) {
   changeSelection(row, col, true, false);
}
```

What now after this? The event fires but the renderer does not show that now a checkbox has been check if it was unchecked and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

The Table data is stored in a `TableModel`, which is the OP `MVC` pattern to `JTable` in Swing, and that what you need to deal with, so if you want to update your table you need to `fireTableCellUpdated` from `AbstractTableModel`.

so you may want to do something like this:

```
public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    //implements the needed methods.

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        //code
        fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
    }
}
```

Read more about [`AbstractTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html)